# Joomla 3.5.1 on Openshift MySQL 5.5 out of sort memory

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, openshift

Fresh install of Joomla on OpenShift and when I open go to Extensions > Modules, i get the following error message:

```
Error

Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size SQL=SELECT a.id, a.title, a.note, a.position, a.module, a.language,a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.published as published, e.enabled as enabled, a.access, a.ordering, a.publish_up, a.publish_down,l.title AS language_title, l.image AS language_image,uc.name AS editor,ag.title AS access_level,MIN(mm.menuid) AS pages,e.name AS name FROM `#__modules` AS a LEFT JOIN `#__languages` AS l ON l.lang_code = a.language LEFT JOIN #__users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN #__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access LEFT JOIN #__modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = a.id LEFT JOIN #__extensions AS e ON e.element = a.module WHERE (a.published IN (0, 1)) AND a.client_id = 0 AND e.client_id =0 GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.note, a.position, a.module, a.language,a.checked_out,a.checked_out_time, a.published, a.access, a.ordering, l.title, l.image, uc.name, ag.title, e.name,l.lang_code, uc.id, ag.id, mm.moduleid, e.element, a.publish_up, a.publish_down,e.enabled
```

I've confirmed MySQL has the buffer size set to 128K and I found documentation that I should be able to set it using environment variable.
However, this is not working. I checked my.cnf and sort_buffer_size isn't even using a variable. It's set to 128k.

Please advise how to fix this as it basically makes joomla unusable on OpenShift.

Thanks!

Comment: In the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf , set sort_buffer_size to 256K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_buffer_size` defaults to 256K I think on newer versions of MySQL - but you may be running an older version where it defaults to 128K.

On a very large Joomla website, we were forced to set the sort_buffer_size to 128M. You can set it by editing the `/etc/my.cnf` file (location might be different on your server) and adding the following to it:

```
sort_buffer_size=128M
```

Then restart MySQL, and check if the problem goes way. If it doesn't,then login to phpMyAdmin (as root), and check if the new value has taken effect (under the "Variables" tab).